# Python: looking for a way to sleep the iterator for N sec/min during asyncio semophore after running certain number or records

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, semaphore

Based on below code, need help within asyncio Semaphore process way to sleep for certain time i.e. 10 sec after triggering N records (i.e. 5 records) while running the loop (sequential trigger (preferred) or random trigger order is okay). Way I have designed is a limited parallel asyncio where n (i.e. 2) records are process at a given time.
Or is there a better solution with configurable value as I will be processing huge volume of array data (10mil)

using python 3.6

```
from time import time
import asyncio

async def square(x, a):
    print(f'start {x}', a)
    await asyncio.sleep(a)
    print(f'end {x}', a)
    return a * a

async def main(limit_number):
    s = asyncio.Semaphore(limit_number)
    async def func(x, a):
        with await s:
            return await square(x, a)
    counter = 0
    tasks = []
    list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    for index, a in enumerate(list):
            if index % 5 == 0 and index > 1:
                print("sleep >>>>>>>>>>> 10s")
                counter +=1
                await asyncio.sleep(10)   ## "need help to correctly pass the sleep to generate below expected output"
            tasks.append(func(counter, a))
    completed, pending = await asyncio.wait(tasks)
    print([t.result() for t in completed])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main(2))
    loop.close()
```

Current output

```
sleep >>>>>>>>>>> 10s
sleep >>>>>>>>>>> 10s
start 6 6
start 1 1
end 6 6
end 1 1
start 7 7
start 2 2
end 7 7
end 2 2
start 8 8
start 3 3
end 8 8
end 3 3
start 9 9
start 0 0
end 9 9
end 0 0
start 4 4
start 10 10
end 4 4
end 10 10
start 5 5
end 5 5
[36, 64, 16, 1, 9, 100, 49, 81, 25, 4, 0]
```

Expected output

```
start 0 0
start 0 1
end 0 0
start 0 2
end 0 1
start 0 3
end 0 2
start 0 4
sleep >>>>>>>>>>> 10s
end 0 3
start 1 5
end 0 4
start 1 6
end 1 5
start 1 7
end 1 6
start 1 8
end 1 7
start 1 9
sleep >>>>>>>>>>> 10s
end 1 8
start 2 10
end 1 9
end 2 10
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100]
```

Comment: What is the big task that you are trying to solve?

Comment: @md2perpe, after every interval i'm trying to capture the stats in a file and updating the token value for next set of data, if that helps

Comment: Unfortunately not. I don't see the connection to your code.

Comment: so there isnt a way to add sleep or some pause after certain interval when processing array data?

Comment: This feels like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/1163269).

Comment: its a working code post request, where token refresh is needed every hour to establish the authentication. rather then using try and except with status code check for 401, I'm looking to renew token value after certain number of record processed (above example represent 5). Does that clarify @md2perpe? There are other limit but all are take care except having issue when process huge data that take more than 1hr. If the dataset less no issue when process as it gets complete within hr.

Comment: Yes, that makes the big situation clearer. But it looks like you have two problems: 1) the token renewals, the way you have added them, are run before the sequence of post requests, and 2) results come in disorder.

Comment: Why don't you use a thread for the token renewal?